# Find a group of objects in an array with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**Question has been moved to CodeReview:** https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/154804/find-a-list-of-objects-in-an-array-with-javascript

Having an array of objects - such as numbers - what would be the most optimal (Memory and CPU efficiency) way if finding a sub group of objects? As an example:

`demoArray = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`
Finding `[3,4,5]` would return `2`, while looking for `60` would return `-1`.
The function must allow for wrapping, so finding `[6,7,1,2]` would return `5`

I have a current working solution, but I'd like to know if it could be optimized in any way.

```js
var arr = [
  1,
  5,2,6,8,2,
  3,4,3,10,9,
  1,5,7,10,3,
  5,6,2,3,8,
  9,1]
var idx = -1
var group = []
var groupSize = 0

function findIndexOfGroup(g){
  group = g
  groupSize = g.length
  var beginIndex = -2
  
  while(beginIndex === -2){
    beginIndex = get()
  }
  
  return beginIndex
}

function get(){
    idx = arr.indexOf(group[0], idx+1);
    
    if(idx === -1 || groupSize === 1){
      return idx;
    }
    var prevIdx = idx
    
    for(var i = 1; i < groupSize; i++){
      idx++
      
      if(arr[getIdx(idx)] !== group[i]){
        idx = prevIdx
        break
      }
      
      if(i === groupSize - 1){
        return idx - groupSize + 1
      }
    }
    return -2
}

function getIdx(idx){
  if(idx >= arr.length){
    return idx - arr.length
  }
  return idx
}

console.log(findIndexOfGroup([4,3,10])) // Normal
console.log(findIndexOfGroup([9,1,1,5])) // Wrapping
```

Comment: Can you make any assumptions on the contents of the array? It looks like you do not, but that would help in speeding things up. This question might also be better suited on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: I will actually post it on there - sorry SO is my go-to :) Right now, the array will only be numbers - if anything, they will stay primitive types

Comment: No worries, I do like the question. It looks pretty good to me. You will definitely find interested people on CodeReview.SX :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [reminder operator `%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) for keeping the index in the range of the array with a check for each element of the search array with [`Array#every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every).

```js
function find(search, array) {
    var index = array.indexOf(search[0]);

    while (index !== -1) {
        if (search.every(function (a, i) { return a === array[(index + i) % array.length]; })) {
            return index;
        }
        index = array.indexOf(search[0], index + 1);
    }
    return -1;
}

console.log(find([3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));          //  2
console.log(find([6, 7, 1, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));       //  5
console.log(find([60], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]));               // -1
console.log(find([3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 9])); //  6
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: This will not work if a pattern partially matches and then later does match: `find([3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 3, 4, 5, 9])` for example.

Comment: @Justastudent, thanks for the hint, please see edit.

Answer (score 0):

My take on the problem is to use `slice()` and compare each subarray of length equal to the group's length to the actual group array. Might take a bit long, but the code is short enough:

```js
// The array to run the tests on
var arr = [
  1,
  5, 2, 6, 8, 2,
  3, 4, 3, 10, 9,
  1, 5, 7, 10, 3,
  5, 6, 2, 3, 8,
  9, 1
];
// Check arrays for equality, provided that both arrays are of the same length
function arraysEqual(array1, array2) {
  for (var i = array1.length; i--;) {
    if (array1[i] !== array2[i])
      return false;
  }
  return true;
}
// Returns the first index of a subarray matching the given group of objects
function findIndexOfGroup(array, group) {
  // Get the length of both arrays
  var arrayLength = array.length;
  var groupLength = group.length;
  // Extend array to check for wrapping
  array = array.concat(array);
  var i = 0;
  // Loop, slice, test, return if found
  while (i < arrayLength) {
    if (arraysEqual(array.slice(i, i + groupLength), group))
      return i;
    i++;
  }
  // No index found
  return -1;
}
// Tests
console.log(findIndexOfGroup(arr,[4,3,10])); // Normal
console.log(findIndexOfGroup(arr,[9,1,1,5])); // Wrapping
console.log(findIndexOfGroup(arr,[9,2,1,5])); // Not found
```

If the group is longer than the array, some errors might occur, but I leave it up to you to extend the method to deal with such situations.